# Prove the given condition based on max and min of a function

Tags: calculus

> A function $y=f(x) $satisfies the condition $f’(x) \sin x +f(x)\cos x =1$, $f(x)$ being bounded when $x\to 0$. For $I=\int_0^{\pi/2} f(x).dx$, prove that $\pi/2<I<\frac{\pi^2}{4}$

Here, $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$

I managed to prove $I>\pi/2$, but I am not able to do the other part. How is it done?

Comment: is I really $>\pi/2$ see https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-pi%2F2%2Bint_0%5E%28pi%2F2%29+sinx%2Fx

Comment: I am getting $I<\pi/2$ using $\sin x\le x$

Comment: Isn't $f(x) = x/\sin x$?